# Reading file from WEB-INF folder - NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, tomcat, file-io, jersey-2.0

I have created a Jersey REST project, and I am running on a Tomcat server having exported it as a WAR file. One of the operations that the project carries out is reading a CSV file from the WEB-INF directory.

However when attempting to do this, I am seeing a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException being thrown. The read is being done from the following location:

```
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/mycsvfile.csv";
```

..which corresponds to the location in my project structure. The application is having no issue reading the file in JUnit tests, it's only when deployed that I see this issue.

Is there a specific location where resources such as files should be placed in a web based project?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: at runtime the folder `WebContent` does not exist. Also its better to acquire the file as a *resource*: `Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/resources/mycsvfile.csv")));`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but still no luck. I'm seeing a null pointer exception now which indicated that the file still cannot be found.

Comment: did you keep the leading slash (`/`)?

Comment: Yep, I tried with and without. I'm now looking at the ServletContext to get the real path using context.getRealPath(("/WEB-INF...). This seems to return the full deployed location.

Comment: The above worked. :) Thanks for your input.